# How to use both rocket pants and doorkeeper in the same rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, rest, oauth-2.0

I'm creating a JSON API for my application. I'd like to use rocket_pants for the JSON API and doorkeeper to provide OAuth2 support.

My problem is that it seems that once I change my controller to extend rocket pants controller  the doorkeeper methods are no longer available.

So, as soon as I'm changing the declaration of the controller to `class Api::V1::ApiController < RocketPants::Base`, I'm getting this error:

```
in `<class:ApiController>': undefined method `doorkeeper_for' for Api::V1::ApiController:Class (NoMethodError)
```

It probably makes sense, since rocket pants has no way of knowing about doorkeeper, but I'd like to know what I should do in order to make it recognize doorkeeper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use doorkeeper 0.4.1 or up, you can add the doorkeeper filter to your controller:

```
class MetalController < ActionController::Metal
  include AbstractController::Callbacks # you might want to skip this for rocket_pants based controller
  include ActionController::Head
  include Doorkeeper::Helpers::Filter

  doorkeeper_for :all

  def index
    self.response_body = { :ok => true }.to_json
  end
end
```

Since rocket_pants already includes `AbstractController::Callbacks` you can skip it, so your controller would look like:

```
class MetalController < RocketPants::Base
  include ActionController::Head
  include Doorkeeper::Helpers::Filter

  version 1

  doorkeeper_for :all
end
```

This page on the wiki also might be useful: https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/wiki/ActionController::Metal-with-doorkeeper